# What's the correct number of workers to put on gathering vespene and minerals in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In StarCraft 1, I didn't halt worker production until I had 3 for every 2 mineral patches, and 3 for each vespene geyser.  This was my own personal guideline, and I have no idea how efficient/wasteful it was.

What's an appropriate guideline for maximum income rate in StarCraft 2?  Does it differ by race?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I know some people have answered this but I thought I could add a little data.

For gas, full saturation is 3, however the third isn't worth as much as the first two. As a result its worth getting a second geyser before putting a third worker on the first.

This is also true for minerals as shown by this graph:
[image]

As you can see after your first 16 workers the gain per worker starts to decrease dramatically.  As a result when you start an expansion you should shift any excess workers (over 16) to the new expansion.

The original research can be found in this paper: [Worker Income Efficiency in Starcraft II](http://docs.google.com/fileview?id=0B3X9N0NR7fRtYzAzN2RlZTAtZDlkNS00M2Y2LTlkMGQtZGZkM2M5ZTA4Mjc0&hl=en) By Chet 'Cheticus' V.  The paper reports original data collection and methods, as well as the formula's uses for the 'least squares regression.'

Comment: Can you cite the formula for that graph?

Comment: @Joe added to my answer

Comment: Note, that the number of 16 workers is only valid if there are 8 mineral patches (as can be found in your source)

Comment: @JochenJung agreed.  Since 8 mineral patches is the standard for maps, 16 is the "normal" number.  However, we can abstract this to 2 per mineral until all patches have 2, and then 3 max.

Comment: It does show that 24 works gathers faster than 16 though based on the graph. If you have 24 at all expansions you'd be gathering faster than just 16.

Comment: @Shogun yes, but you have to consider the cost/benefit analysis of an additional 8*expansion supply that can't be used for your army.  I'm not saying I don't build more than 16, but when I transfer I usually transfer everything in excess of 16.

Comment: I've heard that 4 workers are required for full saturation of a far diagonal vespene geyser. Is this true? Whenever I've tried it, it always seems like one of them is just sitting outside the assimilator.

Comment: @Carl yes, but the gain on that fourth worker is in the 10-20 gas per minute range.

Comment: @Shogun: 16 spread over 8 patches is faster than 18 spread over 6 patches.

Comment: @tze, how can you easily transfer your excess in 16? Hotkeys? Clicking?

Comment: @Juan box all my workers and preform the following calculation: Workers - 2*Extractor - 16 = number to transfer.  Box accordingly and subtract (shift click) if I have extra.

Comment: @Juan I demonstrate the technique in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OIR4DGI6gM)

Comment: @JuanManuel: Note how each row is 8 units long. Two rows per base is optimal saturation. Three rows is maximal saturation. Simply count how much there are on the second page (if there is one), add *8* to that number and then select that amount of number to transfer them to your expansion...

Answer (score 4):

Same values: 3 per gas, 3 per patch. I think that the in game tips also say that, but I got that info from looking at high-level replays.

Some players prefer less, though, for various reasons - less wasted supplies, for example.

Answer (score 3):

3 is what is necessary to "saturate" a patch or geyser.

However, I like to play with about 5 for every two patches or so and 3 on each geyser.

This *almost* maxes out gathering speed, wastes fewer resources, and scales nicely when a patch is exhausted.

Answer (score 3):

Since SC2 is much more economy based than SC:BW the golden rule is **never stop producing workers**!
If you get much more than 3 per patch: EXPAND and do a miner-slide (moving workers from main to expansion).

Comment: This isn't that simple for Zerg..