# Does having more than 3 worker per resource point decrease gathering efficiency?

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the correct number of workers to put on gathering vespene and minerals in StarCraft 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/whats-the-correct-number-of-workers-to-put-on-gathering-vespene-and-minerals-in)

- Are more better?
- Do more workers per resource point hurt production?

Comment: @Kevin: <3 *[†: Hah, badp, but that trick no longer works anyway, so I'm putting a pseudo-edit-summary style comment, by dagger! ♪]*

Comment: Having more than 3 workers on gas is wasteful, assuming an optimal command center location. Having more than 3 workers on a mineral node helps, but at vastly diminishing returns.

There's been a couple threads like this lately, let's see if I can find one of Tzenes' charts...

Edit: Here you go! http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/whats-the-correct-number-of-workers-to-put-on-gathering-vespene-and-minerals-in/1509#1509